# Retrieving the COM class factory for component Access Denied Error

Tags: loadrunner, clsid

While trying to run Azure Pipeline for Loadrunner Professional Tests, got below error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E933439A-81A1-11D4-8EEE-0050DA6171E8} failed due to the following error:80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

1. Somehow figured out that this CLSID is associated with wlrun.LrEngine, but i couldn't find wrlrun.LrEngine in Dcom application list (dcomcnfg.exe) in my machine.
2. I can see the wlrun.LrEngine in registry, but cannot see in the Dcom config folder.  (Component Service >> My Computer >> DCOM config )
3. What could be the possible reason behind this, or am i searching in wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by opening Dcom Config for 32-bit Applications:

- Go to Start | Run
- Type MMC -32 and click Ok
- Go to File | Select Add/Remove Snap-in option
- Add Component Services option in Management Console application
- Then follow the path to Dcom Config

And Boom! i found wlrun.LrEngine under Dcom.

- And further gave appropriate permissions to it (Right click >> properties >> security >> Click customize - edit and add permissions)