# Loadrunner CLIControllerApp.exe event timeout issue from Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, loadrunner, microfocus

I have created an Azure pipeline wherein I make use of CMD task to trigger a Load Runner Scenario on a machine which is hosted On-Premises but I am getting failure for the same. Please find the setup details below

Load Runner Controller:- My Personal Laptop (No License, I am using LR community Free version as this is a POC)

Azure Pipeline:- On-Cloud

Scenario:- Azure Pipeline will trigger the CMD task which will then trigger the Load Runner Scenraio on my local machine

I have added my laptop to the Agent Pools-> Default Pools for the Azure Project I created.
I can see my machine under Agents as Online and I can execute a series of other commands from Azure CMD task on my Laptop, the issue is only with LoadRunner execution

[image]

I find it strange cause I can execute the same command locally on my laptop  using Command prompt perfectly

There is an issue with this command when I execute it from Azure Pipeline!! I can run other commands from the pipeline without any issue!

Please find below the snapshot of the pipeline cmd task

[image]

I am using the below command for triggering a Load Runner Scenraio

LR Installation Location:- cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\bin

LoadRunner Execution Command:- CLIControllerApp.exe -TestPath C:\temp\LR_Scenarios\MSD365_Demo.lrs -Run -ResultName C:\temp\LR_Results

But I am getting the error as Wait CLICntrlService_Ready_Event timeout! Please find the error snap below.

[image]

I did find one thread for this issue where they said that- you need LR license to use the CLI tool!! I dont see any invalid license code in wlrun log file but I feel its related to this license issue. Please find the link below which I reffered

https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Professional-User/Licensing-Error-with-LoadRunner-CLIControllerApp-exe/m-p/2702193

I have also done multiple re-installation of Load Runner on my machine so I dont think it has anything to do with installation.

Need help, do let me know if anyone else has faced this issue and have a solution other than licensing cause I am doing an RnD piece and cant buy a license. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hi Cece Dong, Apologies for delayed response I did try all what you mentioned but they didn't work and I found a similar issue listed on community forum whichpointed out to License issue so I kind of gave up on this one. My next step is to create a distributed setup where Jenkins will be on one machine and I will add a Controller Machine as a slave to jenkins and trigger a test run on the controller machine.

https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Professional-User/Licensing-Error-with-LoadRunner-CLIControllerApp-exe/m-p/2702193

Comment: The reason I am creating a distributed setup is to ensure that I can trigger the build remotely but when it comes to triggering th build from the cloud on a local on premise machine there is soe issue leading to timeout. Which I am thinking is due to the license as mentioned at the link shared in the comment above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently successfully tried integrating using LoadRunner professional tests (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Micro-Focus.LoadRunnerProfessionalTestsAutomation) and it worked like charm, let me know the exact error and i might help you. Its simple enough.

Here is link to one of the issue i faced and how i solved it.
[Retrieving the COM class factory for component Access Denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017937/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-access-denied-error)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an installation or configuration problem of Micro Focus's LoadRunner Enterprise product.

For LoadRunner Enterprise issue, please re-ask it on the official forum:
https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Enterprise/ct-p/PerformanceCenter

Comment: The same command work when I run it locally from CMD and from jenkins on my local machine. So I am not sure if its an installation issue, plus I re-did the installation multiple times just to rule that out

Answer (score 0):

In order to narrow down the issue, you may try the following items:

1. Set variable `system.debug` to `true` in your pipeline to see whether you can get more log.
2. Check the account that runs the Azure Pipelines Agent service, and use this account to run the command locally to see whether you can get a successful result.
3. Check the following extension to see whether they can help you:

   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=LoadRunner&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: I'd rather go with Plugins available for Azure Devops to run loadrunner tests, as it provides more features and easier to setup.

Comment: @Cece Dong: Apologies for delay I didn't see anyone responding to this thread and hence closed it post fiding a smiliar issue listed at the load runner Community Forum

https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Professional-User/Licensing-Error-with-LoadRunner-CLIControllerApp-exe/m-p/2702193

I did check the account that runs the Azure Devops pipeline and I gave it Admin Privilages on the Agent machine it does triggers the initiation but the controller.cli fails to start and times out

I already used Load Runner Professional extension frm the market place but it fails to work.

Comment: @VishalChepuri:- I did try usig the plug in for Load Runner to trigger tests but it did not work and ths I tried creating simple pipeline with commandline call to trigger the test

Comment: @PankajHarde I have recently successfully tried integrating using loadRunner professional tests and it worked like charm, let me know the exact error and i might help you. Its simple enough. Here is link to one of the issue i faced and how i solved it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017937/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-access-denied-error

Comment: @Vishal Chepuri, thanks for looking into this and reverting back, I tried what you shared on the link above but it did not solve the problem. I am anyways using the CLIControllerApp.exe -TestPath C:\temp\LR_Scenarios\MSD365_Demo.lrs -Run -ResultName C:\temp\LR_Results command. I have edited my problem statement above to give a better idea of what I am doing. Requesting you to please see if you can help or provide the steps which you implemented at your end if mine are incorrect. Thanks

Comment: @Vishal Chepuri, I guess you were using the "Execute Load Runner Professional Test Plugin" and for that you made settings at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017937/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-access-denied-error". I tired this plug in before but it was failing but after your suggestion I though of using this plugin again and it "Works like a Charm" Amazing.So this plugin is now working the only issue now is, for reason it did not capture any results value. Will keep you posted

Comment: Glad i could help. Will copy the same to Answers.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Chepuri and @ Cece Dong, I will Mark the answer which Vishal has shared and I will also update my question with the Entire steps I did to get this working.

I also got few error regarding execution policies which I fixed following the steps at the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

Someone down rated my Question :(. I will update the entire query and provide all the steps as I finish the documentation on this piece. Thanks again!