# PowerShell script doesn't work with docx files as COM-objects while being run via GitLab CI/CD

Tags: powershell, com, gitlab-ci, docx

## Introduction

There is a [**Gostdown** project on GitLab](https://gitlab.iaaras.ru/iaaras/gostdown/) which is dedicated to styling `.docx` files in accordance with national standards for documentation. The pipeline of getting a final version of a `.docx` document is:

1. One puts all needed info into `.md` files.
2. Pandoc generates single *simple* `.docx` file.
3. [PowerShell script](https://gitlab.iaaras.ru/iaaras/gostdown/-/blob/master/build.ps1) *styles* it in a preset way.

## Problem

The problem occures on step 3: script works fine locally but can't handle `.docx` file as COM-object if I run it via gitlab-runner on the same machine.

The message I get on GitLab is:

[image: Error]

## Possible reason

This message pops up on every call of anything related to this variable:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
```

It seems PowerShell doesn't work with COM if it runs with gitlab-runner **but** I know **it did work** on another machines (on project's author machine at least) without any *super* special settings.

Script itself:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$template,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$md,
    [string]$docx,
    [string]$pdf,
    [switch]$embedfonts,
    [switch]$counters
)

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($docx) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pdf))
{
  Write-error "-docx or -pdf must be specified"
  exit 113
}

$exe = "pandoc.exe"

$template = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($template)

$md = $md | % { [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($_ )}

$is_docx_temporary = $False

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($docx))
{
  $docx = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFilename() + ".docx"
  $is_docx_temporary = $True
}
else
{
  $docx = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($docx)
}

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pdf))
{
  $pdf = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($pdf)
}

$tempdocx = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFilename() + ".docx"

write-host "Executing Pandoc..."
&$exe $md -o $tempdocx --lua-filter ./linebreaks.lua --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc --reference-doc $template

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
  Write-error "Pandoc execution has failed"
  exit 111
}

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$curdir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Set-Location -Path $curdir

$word.ScreenUpdating = $False

$doc = $word.Documents.Open($template)
$doc.Activate()
$selection = $word.Selection

# Save under a new name as soon as possible to prevent auto-saving
# (and polluting) the template
write-host "Saving..."
$doc.SaveAs([ref]$docx)
if (-not $?)
{
  $doc.Close()
  $word.Quit()
  exit 112
}

write-host "Inserting main text..."
if ($selection.Find.Execute("%MAINTEXT%^13", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, "",   `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceNone))
{
  $start = $Selection.Range.Start
  $Selection.InsertFile($tempdocx)
  $end = $Selection.Range.End
  $inserted_tables = $doc.Range([ref]$start, [ref]$end).Tables

  # Check if there is anything after the main text
  $selection.WholeStory()
  $totalend = $Selection.Range.End

  # If there is nothing after the main text, remove the extra CR which
  # mystically appears out of nowhere in that case
  if ($end -ge ($totalend - 1))
  {
    $selection.Collapse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdCollapseDirection]::wdCollapseEnd)  | out-null
    $selection.MoveLeft([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdCharacter, 1, `
                        [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdMovementType]::wdExtend)  | out-null
    $selection.Delete() | out-null
  }
}

write-host "Searching styles..."
foreach ($style in $doc.Styles)
{
  switch ($style.NameLocal)
  {
    'TableStyleContributors'  {$TableStyleContributors = $style; break}
    'TableStyleAbbreviations' {$TableStyleAbbreviations = $style; break}
    'TableStyleGost'          {$TableStyleGost = $style; break}
    'TableStyleGostNoHeader'  {$TableStyleGostNoHeader = $style; break}
    'UnnumberedHeading1'      {$UnnumberedHeading1 = $style; break}
    'UnnumberedHeading1NoTOC' {$UnnumberedHeading1NoTOC = $style; break}
    'UnnumberedHeading2'      {$UnnumberedHeading2 = $style; break}
  }
}

$BodyText = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBuiltinStyle]::wdStyleBodyText
$Heading1 = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBuiltinStyle]::wdStyleHeading1
$Heading2 = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBuiltinStyle]::wdStyleHeading2
$Heading3 = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBuiltinStyle]::wdStyleHeading3

$bullets = [char]0x2014,[char]0xB0,[char]0x2014,[char]0xB0
$numberposition = 0,0.75,1.75,3
$textposition = 0.85,1.75,3,3.5
$tabposition = 1,1.75,3,3.5
$format_nested = "%1)","%1.%2)","%1.%2.%3)","%1.%2.%3.%4)"
$format_headers = "%1","%1.%2","%1.%2.%3","%1.%2.%3.%4"
$format_single = "%1)","%2)","%3)","%4)"

write-host "Handling list templates..."

foreach ($tt in $doc.ListTemplates)
{
  for ($il = 1; $il -le $tt.ListLevels.Count -and $il -le 4; $il++)
  {
    $level = $tt.ListLevels.Item($il)
    $bullet = ($level.NumberStyle -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListNumberStyle]::wdListNumberStyleBullet)
    $arabic = ($level.NumberStyle -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListNumberStyle]::wdListNumberStyleArabic)
    $roman  = ($level.NumberStyle -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListNumberStyle]::wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman)
    
    if ($bullet)
    {
      if ($level.NumberFormat -ne " ")
      {
        $level.NumberFormat = $bullets[$il - 1] + ""
      }
      $level.NumberPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($numberposition[$il - 1])
      $level.Alignment = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListLevelAlignment]::wdListLevelAlignLeft
      $level.TextPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($textposition[$il - 1])
      $level.TabPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($tabposition[$il - 1])
      $level.ResetOnHigher = $il - 1
      $level.StartAt = 1
      $level.Font.Size = 12
      $level.Font.Name = "PT Serif"
      if ($il % 2 -eq 0)
      {
        $level.Font.Position = -4
      }
      $level.LinkedStyle = ""
      $level.TrailingCharacter = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdTrailingCharacter]::wdTrailingTab
    }
    
    if (($arabic -and ($level.NumberFormat -ne $format_headers[$il - 1])) -or $roman)
    {
      if ($level.NumberFormat -ne " " )
      {
        if ($arabic)
        {
          $level.NumberFormat = $format_nested[$il - 1]
        }
        if ($roman)
        {
          $level.NumberStyle = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListNumberStyle]::wdListNumberStyleArabic;
          $level.NumberFormat = $format_single[$il - 1]
        }
      }
      $level.NumberPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($numberposition[$il - 1])
      $level.Alignment = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdListLevelAlignment]::wdListLevelAlignLeft
      $level.TextPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($textposition[$il - 1])
      $level.TabPosition = $word.CentimetersToPoints($tabposition[$il - 1])
      $level.ResetOnHigher = $il - 1
      $level.StartAt = 1
      $level.Font.Size = 12
      $level.Font.Name = "PT Serif"
      $level.LinkedStyle = ""
      $level.TrailingCharacter = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdTrailingCharacter]::wdTrailingTab
    }
  }
}

# Disable grammar checking (it takes time and spews out error messages)
$doc.GrammarChecked = $True

$ntables = 0

write-host "Handling tables..."

# Loop over other tables
for ($t = 1; $t -le $inserted_tables.Count; $t++)
{
  $table = $inserted_tables.Item($t)
  
  if ($table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Style.NameLocal -eq "ContributorsTable")
  {
    $table.Select()
    $selection.ClearParagraphAllFormatting()
    $pf = $selection.paragraphFormat
    $pf.LeftIndent = 0
    $pf.RightIndent = 0
    $pf.SpaceBefore = 0
    $pf.SpaceBeforeAuto = $False
    $pf.SpaceAfter = 0
    $pf.SpaceAfterAuto = $False

    $table.Style = $TableStyleContributors

    foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
    {
      # Row height can not be set in table style
      $row.Height = $word.CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
      
      # Alignment and line spacing are set in table style, but are not applied (low priority?)
      # So we set them explicitly
      $row.Select()
      $pf = $selection.paragraphFormat
      $pf.Alignment = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphLeft
      $pf.LineSpacingRule = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdLineSpacing]::wdLineSpaceSingle
    }
    
    continue
  }
  
  if ($table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Style.NameLocal -eq "AbbreviationsTable")
  {
    $table.Style = $TableStyleAbbreviations
    $table.Select()
    $pf = $selection.paragraphFormat
    $selection.ClearParagraphAllFormatting()
    $pf.LeftIndent = 0
    $pf.RightIndent = 0
    $pf.SpaceBefore = 0
    $pf.SpaceBeforeAuto = $False
    $pf.SpaceAfter = 0
    $pf.SpaceAfterAuto = $False
    continue
  }
  
  # This is to fix the widths of the columns
  $table.AllowAutoFit = $False
      
  # Numbered equations are 2-column tables without titles and borders, and with equations in both columns
  if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($table.Title) `
    -and (-not $table.Rows.Item(1).Cells.Borders.Item([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBorderType]::wdBorderBottom).Visible) `
      -and ($table.Columns.Count -eq 2) `
      -and ($table.Cell(1,1).Range.OMaths.Count -eq 1) `
      -and ($table.Cell(1,2).Range.OMaths.Count -eq 1))
  {
    # There can be multiple equations (rows) in one table
    foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
    {
      # After removing the equation, the text contents remains
      if ($row.Cells.Item(2).Range.OMaths.Count -ne 0)
      {
        $row.Cells.Item(2).Range.OMaths.Item(1).Remove()
      }
                
      $row.Cells.Item(2).VerticalAlignment = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdCellVerticalAlignment]::wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
      $row.Cells.Item(2).Select()
      $selection.ClearParagraphAllFormatting()
      $pf = $selection.paragraphFormat
      $pf.LeftIndent = $word.CentimetersToPoints(0)
      $pf.RightIndent = $word.CentimetersToPoints(0)
      $pf.Alignment = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphRight
      $pf.SpaceBefore = 0
      $pf.SpaceBeforeAuto = $False
      $pf.SpaceAfter = 0
      $pf.SpaceAfterAuto = $False
      $pf.LineSpacingRule = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdLineSpacing]::wdLineSpaceSingle
      $pf.CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
      $pf.CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
      $pf.LineUnitBefore = 0
      $pf.LineUnitAfter = 0
    }
  }
  else # Ordinary tables
  {
    # Count only tables with title (and number)
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($table.Title))
    {
      $ntables = $ntables + 1
    }
    
    $table.Select()
    
    $pf = $selection.paragraphFormat
    $pf.LineSpacingRule = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdLineSpacing]::wdLineSpaceSingle
    
    # If the first row has line under it, then it is a table with a header row
    if ($table.Rows.Item(1).Cells.Borders.Item([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBorderType]::wdBorderBottom).Visible)
    {
      $table.Style = $TableStyleGost
    }
    else # table without header row
    {
      $table.Style = $TableStyleGostNoHeader
    }
    
    # Fix alignment of display-math objects so they math the aligment of text in the cells
    foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
    {
      foreach ($cell in $row.Cells)
      {
        foreach ($math in $cell.Range.OMaths)
        {
          if ($math.Type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdOMathType]::wdOMathDisplay)
          {
            $al = $cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment
            if ($al -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphRight)
            {
              $math.Justification = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdOMathJc]::wdOMathJcRight;
            }
            elseif ($al -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphLeft)
            {
              $math.Justification = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdOMathJc]::wdOMathJcLeft;
            }
            elseif ($al -eq [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphCenter)
            {
              $math.Justification = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdOMathJc]::wdOMathJcCenter;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

write-host "Updating paragraph styles..."

$heading1namelocal = $doc.styles.Item([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdBuiltinStyle]::wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal
$nchapters = 0
$nfigures = 0
$nreferences = 0
$nappendices = 0

foreach ($par in $doc.Paragraphs)
{
  $namelocal = $par.Range.CharacterStyle.NameLocal
  if ($namelocal -eq "UnnumberedHeadingOne")
  {
    $par.Style = $UnnumberedHeading1
  }
  elseif ($namelocal -eq "AppendixHeadingOne")
  {
    $par.Style = $UnnumberedHeading1
    $nappendices = $nappendices + 1
  }
  elseif ($namelocal -eq "UnnumberedHeadingOneNoTOC")
  {
    $par.Style = $UnnumberedHeading1NoTOC
  }
  elseif ($namelocal -eq "UnnumberedHeadingTwo")
  {
    $par.Style = $UnnumberedHeading2
  }
  else
  {
    $namelocal = $par.Style.NameLocal
    # Make source core paragraphs smaller
    if ($namelocal -eq "Source Code")
    {
      $par.Range.Font.Size = 10.5
    }
    # No special style for first paragraph to avoid unwanted space
    # between first and second paragraphs
    elseif ($namelocal -eq "First Paragraph")
    {
      $par.Style = $BodyText
    }
    elseif ($namelocal -eq $heading1namelocal)
    {
      $nchapters = $nchapters + 1
    }
    elseif ($namelocal -eq "Captioned Figure")
    {
      $nfigures = $nfigures + 1
    }
    elseif ($namelocal -eq "ReferenceItem")
    {
      $nreferences = $nreferences + 1
    }
  }
}

if ($counters)
{
  write-host "Inserting number of chapters, figures, and tables..."
  $selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
  $selection.Find.Execute("%NCHAPTERS%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $nchapters + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null
  $selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
  $selection.Find.Execute("%NFIGURES%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $nfigures + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null
  $selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
  $selection.Find.Execute("%NTABLES%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $ntables + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null
  $selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
  $selection.Find.Execute("%NREFERENCES%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $nreferences + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null
  $selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
  $selection.Find.Execute("%NAPPENDICES%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $nappendices + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null
}
       
write-host "Increasing math font size..."

foreach ($math in $doc.OMaths)
{
  # Size equations up a bit to match Paratype font size
  $math.Range.Font.Size = 12.5
}

write-host "Handling INCLUDEs..."
$selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null

while ($selection.Find.Execute("%INCLUDE(*)%^13", $True, $True, $True, $False, $False, $True, `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, "", `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceNone))
{
  if ($selection.Text -match '%INCLUDE\((.*)\)%')
  {
    $filename = $matches[1]
    
    $start = $Selection.Range.Start
    $Selection.InsertFile([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($filename))
    
    if (!$?)
    {
      break
    }
      
    $end = $Selection.Range.End

    # Check if there is anything after the inserted documnt
    $selection.WholeStory()
    $totalend = $Selection.Range.End

    # If there is nothing after the inserted documnt, remove the extra CR which
    # mystically appears out of nowhere in that case
    if ($end -ge ($totalend - 1))
    {
      $selection.Collapse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdCollapseDirection]::wdCollapseEnd)  | out-null
      $selection.MoveLeft([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdCharacter, 1, `
                          [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdMovementType]::wdExtend)  | out-null
      $selection.Delete() | out-null
    }
  }
}

$selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null

write-host "Inserting ToC..."
if ($selection.Find.Execute("%TOC%^13", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, "",   `
       [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceNone))
{
  $doc.TablesOfContents.Add($selection.Range, $False, 9, 9, $False, "", $True, $True, "", $True) | out-null
  
  # Manually add level 1,2,3 headers to ToC
  $toc = $doc.TablesOfContents.Item(1)
  $toc.UseHeadingStyles = $True
  $toc.HeadingStyles.Add($UnnumberedHeading1, 1) | out-null
  $toc.HeadingStyles.Add($UnnumberedHeading2, 2) | out-null
  $toc.HeadingStyles.Add($Heading1, 1) | out-null
  $toc.HeadingStyles.Add($Heading2, 2) | out-null
  $toc.HeadingStyles.Add($Heading3, 3) | out-null
  $toc.Update() | out-null
}

write-host "Inserting number of pages..."

# Seemingly is not needed but who knows
$doc.Repaginate()

# Inserting "section pages" field gets the number of pages wrong, and no way has
# been found to remedy that other than manual update in Word.
# So here is another way to get the number of pages in the section

if ($doc.Sections.Count -gt 1) # two-section template?
{
  $npages = $doc.Sections.Item(2).Range.Information([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdInformation]::wdActiveEndPageNumber) - `
            $doc.Sections.Item(1).Range.Information([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdInformation]::wdActiveEndPageNumber)
}
else
{
  $npages = $doc.Sections.Item(1).Range.Information([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdInformation]::wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
}

$selection.HomeKey([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits]::wdStory) | out-null
$selection.Find.Execute("%NPAGES%", $True, $True, $False, $False, $False, $True, `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue, $False, $npages + "",   `
         [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdReplace]::wdReplaceOne) | out-null

if ($embedfonts)
{
  # Embed fonts (for users who do not have Paratype fonts installed).
  # This costs a few MB in file size
  $word.ActiveDocument.EmbedTrueTypeFonts = $True
  $word.ActiveDocument.DoNotEmbedSystemFonts = $True
  $word.ActiveDocument.SaveSubsetFonts = $True 
}

if (-not $is_docx_temporary)
{
  write-host "Saving docx..."
  $doc.Save()
}

if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pdf))
{
  write-host "Saving PDF..."
  $doc.SaveAs2([ref]$pdf, [ref][Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdSaveFormat]::wdFormatPDF)
}

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()

write-host "Removing temporary files..."
Remove-item -path $tempdocx
if ($is_docx_temporary)
{
  Remove-item -path $docx
}
```

I tried to turn on "Allow service to interact with desktop" in `services.msc` but it didn't help.

Comment: Office apps automation is not recommended for various technical & legal reasons on servers: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem (gostdown on gitlab-runner) by providing additional permissions to `Microsoft Office 97 - 2003 Document` COM-object:

1. Ensure running your gitlab-runner service from user (no systemprofile).
2. Go Start > Run > Type `MMC -32` and hit OK.
3. Go to File > Select Add/Remove Snap-in option > Add `Component Services option` in `Management Console application` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017937/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-access-denied-error)).
4. I saved this console on the Desktop and then run it with Administrator rights.
5. Go to `DCOM Config` and find `Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document` > `Properties`.
6. On `Identity` tab provide user credentials from step 1.
7. On `Security` tab add your user and give all permissions (**this is security risk you need to be aware of**).
8. Restart your system and try any CI/CD Job again.

Some guidelines that might help you to deal with inevitable issues :):

1. When a job with COMObject hangs it doesn't kill a Microsoft Word process. All subsequent jobs will fail. You need to kill the Word process in before or after sections of your job config.
2. In some rare cases Gostdown job might fail or hang with Microsoft Word silently showing a dialogue window about the file being corrupted. You need to click OK manually.
3. Job will fail if you logged on with the gitlab user credentials, so you need to end this user session before running the job. Also, you can give `Microsoft Office 97 - 2003 Document` > `Properties` COM `Interactive` identity and leave user logged on (this might be useful for testing).

Unfortunately, Microsoft Word wasn't built with automation in mind, I hope this will change in the future.

You can read about this issue on the links below:

- [Interop.Word Documents.Open is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837437/interop-word-documents-open-is-null).
- ["Retrieving the COM class factory for component.... error: 80070005 Access is denied." (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785063/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-80070005-access-is-de)
- [Retrieving the COM class factory for component Access Denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017937/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-access-denied-error)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not going to test it out soon probably, but I was able to follow your instructions and run your version of gostdown.